# What is the best time / are the best times for a meeting?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, grammatical-number, formality

I'm about to arrange a meeting with a person. I have a feeling that when I say "What is the best time for a meeting?", I'm sort of forcing them to come up with one option only. I'd like to show them that they can suggest several timeframes and I'll then pick the one that is fine with me.

How do I phrase that? First thing that comes to mind is to use the plural *times*:

> What are the best times to call you?

But the *times* here sounds as in "good old days".

What is the correct way to express this?

Comment: Related: [“When would be the best time” vs. “what would be the best time”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30662/when-would-be-the-best-time-vs-what-would-be-the-best-time).

Comment: Alos related: [Is a range of dates singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/111739/8019).

Comment: This widely used phrasing of the form "best times" is ungrammatical. It cannot be recommended on ELU.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about 'best times'.

Comment: It's time, so *When* is a better word to begin the question. The answer to this post should then naturally follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to say this (taken from an actual email):

> I'd be happy to discuss this on Skype or on the phone. What are some times that could work for you over the next couple days? I'm on pacific time (California).

I've accepted the other answer just because I didn't have anything better - now this one seems to completely answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

Saying

> What is the best time for a meeting?

does not prevent the listener from interpreting it so that more than one time is suggested.

However, saying

> What are the best times for a meeting?

further emphasises giving more than one time.

Both are correct and mean what you want to mean.

Comment: If you want to eliminate all ambiguity, you could rephrase to something like "Can you please suggest a few possible times that would work for a meeting?"